# How to replace the IIFE in export function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im using the following code and its working fine, this is the server.js

```
function start() {
    server.listen(app.get('port'), function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            pr.preProcess();
            console.log('server Listening on port : ' + app.get('port'));
        }
        proxy.web(server);
    });
}
```

this is the module which Im exporting

```
module.exports = function (params) {

Loader.load(params.loadFolder);
    if (_.isEmpty(params)) {
        start();
    } else {
        start();
        Loader.loadFolder(params.loadFolder);
    }
    return {
        start: start,
        pluginLoader: pluginLoader.loadFolderFromPath
    }
}();
```

This module.exports use **()** IIFE (at the end of exports) to make it work,
 and I **want to avoid it** , there is a cleaner way to do that without the brackets at the end?

Comment: take the `()` off, call function where you import it...

Comment: fyi this is called an _IIFE_, immediately invoked function expression

Comment: @PaulS. - Fixed , thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-written as a function declaration/using `function` as a statement

```
module.exports = buildLoader();

function buildLoader(params) {
    Loader.load(params.loadFolder); // are you sure you wanted to do this twice? (cf. else)

    if (_.isEmpty(params)) {
        start();
    } else {
        start();
        Loader.loadFolder(params.loadFolder);
    }

    return {
        start: start,
        pluginLoader: pluginLoader.loadFolderFromPath
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! can you please show how its better to export also the start and pluginLoder?

Comment: I mean if there is better way to write it? I can write 3 exports but not sure if its ok..

Answer (score 0):

take the `()` off, call the function where you import it.:

```
module.exports = function (params) {

Loader.load(params.loadFolder);
    if (_.isEmpty(params)) {
        start();
    } else {
        start();
        Loader.loadFolder(params.loadFolder);
    }
    return {
        start: start,
        pluginLoader: pluginLoader.loadFolderFromPath
    }
}; // take off ()
```

where every you import/require the function, put those back on to get the result.

Comment: Thanks,Since Im new to node.js can you please provide example with my content ?